# how can i change length of meta description from 255

Tags: admin, adminhtml, magento-2.1.3, category-description

I tried to update the **meta descriptions** for my products so that they are different to the normal description.

My main problem is, I need to change meta description length of the products is shown as the meta description.

how can I change the length of meta description from 255 to other lengths in products admin page or pages and which file and code?

Comment: i`m using magento 2.1.3